# Writing digital signage player in webgl?

Tags: c#, java, mono, webgl

we are in the process of determining what would be the best technology to write our signage player . Although we are a C# house with some experience in Java, all the talk has been about Java and Mono. Also the platform we are going to build on would be a linux box.

The player has to be very intelligent and support scheduling, content change triggers by external applications (by web services), time synchronization of content, content show in different portions of the screen, video/live streamed feed etc.

We will also need to create a designer to allow the design team to create webgl content.

There is some OpenGl experience in the company so we could leverage this.

Would this be a good choice?

JD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be an excellent choice IF and only IF you have a good grasp on Javascript or your timeline isn't too tight in case you don't dominate Javascript. If going on a linux box, chances are you're better off with a custom build of Firefox or Chromium running your app alone without the browser parts (menus, tabs, etc).

My team here is working with HTML5+Javascript+Canvas/WebGL on the client side almost exclusively now because it is very fast to develop and needs almost no setup.

Comment: Hola. Thanks for the reply. Can you tell me what you use for WebGl, I have heard of Three.js. Also, are you using web Sockets or a third party solution? We need some way of doing the scheduling of content on the client.

Comment: Sure pal. Our WebGL is completely done in-house because of our specific requirements (it must be content compatible with Android, iPhone, Blackberry and WP7) and most libraries out there are designed with WebGL in mind. The communication is done via Google App Engine's Channel API which gives you a great way to control your WebGL app.